# How to filter an array by an array in typescript and return result

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am able to print the result, how would I return the result here to be assigned to an object

Attribute text is a string that we must split

```
this.childArrayAll.filter(x => x.attributeText1.split(",").forEach(y => {
    if(this.searchFilterForm.controls['types'].value.includes(y) )
        console.log(x);
}))
```

Comment: In order for filter to work, it's callback needs to return a truthy or falsey value. Yours will always return `undefined` from the `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array's [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to do it in clean and optimized way.

```
this.childArrayAll.filter(x => {
    const attributes = x.attributeText1.split(",");

    // Check if there is a match
    return attributes.some(attribute => this.searchFilterForm.controls['types'].value.includes(attribute));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, but you overuse array functions which makes it misunderstandable. And `filter` requires a true/false value, but `forEach` does not return that.

To make your logic simpler, I'd suggest you put an explicit logic for `filter` and return a proper true/false value based on your condition.

```
this.childArrayAll.filter(x => {
  const attributes = x.attributeText1.split(",")
  for(const attribute of attributes) {
    if(this.searchFilterForm.controls['types'].value.includes(attribute)) {
       //found matched attribute
       return true
    }
  }
  //no matched attributes
  return false
})
```